# React re-render all dom even i just change one of them

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React. My purpose is to render a different component when the url parameter changed. I created a demo in codesandbox.

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-swanson-mh2g4?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function getTargetDiv(state: string) {
  switch (state) {
    case "yellow":
      return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>yellow</div>;
    case "red":
      return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>red</div>;
    default:
      return <div style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>default green</div>;
  }
}

const Demo = (): JSX.Element => {
  const query = useQuery();
  const color = query.get("color") ? query.get("color") : "green";
  const targetDiv = getTargetDiv(color as string);
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}>blue</div>
      {targetDiv}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Demo} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

there are 2 div in the page. top div is blue and never changed. when the url parameter "color" changed, a new dom with the color will be insert under the blue one. What I expect is React only re-render the bottom div. but it looks like all dom are re-rendered since the whole page flash. you can try the following url in sandcodebox browser to check the result. Did anyone know why this happened?

https://mh2g4.csb.app?color=yellow

https://mh2g4.csb.app?color=red

Comment: How do you change url? I don't see any button to change it

Comment: How do you navigate to `https://mh2g4.csb.app?color=yellow`? Change in URL and enter?

Comment: I think I know what mistake i made. I change the url direct instead of using a link in react. which reload the whole page. it's too stupid and please forget it.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere, don't be sorry, mate. anyway, I just submit an answer at the same time you replied to this, see if it helps you understand them better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **When you are manually changing the URL in the address bar and submit, it will cause the whole app to reload**

If you don't want the whole page to reload/flash, use internal navigation.

In case you want to navigate internally, you would need to change its route using js or other libraries.

**Here I made a few changes to your example, so you could see how it works**

[image: Edit wandering-star-vsiip]